# Why would these pattern matching be non exhaustive in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have

```
stringTestWord :: String -> String -> [String]
stringTestWord _ [] = [""]
stringTestWord [] _ = [inputString] 
stringTestWord a (c:d)
```

I was quite sure this covers all situations since there is 2 _ for pattern 1 and pattern 2, and for the last pattern I thought list a can be seen as [] or non empty list, and same with (c:d).

Comment: What makes you think that the above code has non-exhaustive patterm matches? Have you tried to compile or evaluate that code snippet? What happens if you do?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-Wall` for warnings? Does GHC report non exhaustive patterns?

Comment: At least right now, your last line isn't part of the *definition* of `stringTestWord`; it's a *call* (albeit one with undefined arguments). Please post code that actual demonstrates the problem.